# python parsing with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a question regarding HTML parsing with BeautifulSoup. The website I am trying to parse is this one: http://www.auc.nl/news-events/events-and-lectures/events-and-lectures.html?page=1&pageSize=40

At first I needed to write a function that would give me all h3-tags and all p-tags. I did that as follows:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib2
    website=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.auc.nl/news-events/events-and-lectures/events-and-lectures.html","r")

    def parseUsingSoup2(content):
        list1=soup.findAll('h3')
        list2=soup.findAll('p')
        return list1+list2        

    parseUsingSoup2(website)
```

The next part of the problem asks for a list of events (there is only one event though on the website) with 4 tuples: the time slot, the title, the type and the description.

I don't really know how to start with that. My first attempt was this:

```
    def GeneratingListofEvents(content):
        event={}
        list=['time', 'title', 'feature', 'description']
        for item in list:
```

However, I have no idea if this is heading in the right direction, and I haven't managed to retrieve for instance the time from the HTML document without typing it manually. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how all the info you need is in `<div class="agendaright">`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.auc.nl/news-events/events-and-lectures/events-and-lectures.html","r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

all = soup.find('div',class_="agendaright")
time = all.find('span',class_="event-time").text
# u'18:00 - 20:00'
title = all.h3.text
# u'Images Without Borders Violence, Visuality, and Landscape in Postwar Ambon, Indonesia'
feature = all.find('span',class_="feature").text
# u' | Lecture'
description = all.find('p',class_="event-description").text
# u'This lecture explores the thematization of the visual and expansion of\nits terrain exemplified by the gigantic hijacked billboards with Jesus\nfaces and the painted murals with Christian themes which arose during\nthe ...'

l = [time,title,feature,description]
```